# Can not deploy Azure Bot

Tags: microsoft-health-bot

Anyone seen any issues where you can't deploy an Azure Health Bot?

The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. (Code: ResourceDeploymentFailure, Target:

Nothing special just searched for Azure Health Bot and chose to create one

Selected Azure Health Bot and create.

Assigned subscription, resource group and gave it a name.